# Cocos2dx crash in simulator of Iphone6 using callfuncND

Tags: crash, cocos2d-x

I use cocos2dx 3.9, but the code crash in simulator of Iphone6 but run correctly in simulator of Iphone4s

```
void BattleHeroIconCSBLayer::doEffectValue4(CCNode *node)
{
    CCCallFuncND *remove = CCCallFuncND::create(node, callfuncND_selector(BattleHeroIconCSBLayer::effectNodeCallBack4), (void*)0);
    auto *seq1 = CCSequence::create(MoveBy::create(1.0, ccp(width - node->getContentSize().width, 0)), remove, NULL);
    auto *seq2 = CCSequence::create(FadeIn::create(0.3), DelayTime::create(0.4), FadeOut::create(0.3), NULL);
    auto *spawn = Spawn::create(seq1, seq2, NULL);
    node->runAction(spawn);
}
```

And in BattleHeroIconCSBLayer::effectNodeCallBack4, I do like this:

```
void BattleHeroIconCSBLayer::effectNodeCallBack4(CCNode* pTarget, void* data)
{
    mBuffBack->setVisible(false);
    pTarget->removeFromParentAndCleanup(true);
}
```

mBuffBack is my member variable, and I get it from cocostudio:

```
mBuffBack = static_cast<Sprite*>(node->getChildByName("mBuffBack"));
```

but I crash in

```
mBuffBack->setVisible(false);
```

using simulator of iphone6;

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to suggestion, I use this code

```
auto remove = CallFunc::create( CC_CALLBACK_0(BattleHeroIconCSBLayer::effectNodeCallBack4, this, node, (void*)0));
```

to instead of

```
CCCallFuncND *remove = CCCallFuncND::create(node, callfuncND_selector(BattleHeroIconCSBLayer::effectNodeCallBack4), (void*)0);
```

and it run ok; but I donot know why;